# How to install Nvidia legacy drivers in Ubuntu 22.10 kinetic

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

I have a graphics card with Nvidia 250 GTS GPU and, when they stopped offering support for them from kernel 5.11, I used the following ppa:

```
https://launchpad.net/~kelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy
```

Now, there is no support for Ubuntu 22.10 kinetic.

Is there any way to be able to install the native Nvidia drivers and not have to use
Nouveau drivers? They work really bad...

PS: the drivers from Nvidia's own website give errors when installing them manually.

Comment: There's no way. Even adding the semi-official https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa that does support 22.10 you'll find out that there are no builds of the 340 driver you need for newer releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1916640/comments/27), the Nvidia legacy drivers are available in Debian Sid. You can download the necessary deb's and install them on *buntu 22.10 as [noted here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-340/+bug/1916640/comments/28).